# Multiple toggle buttons with the same class

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm putting together a simple blog, and one of the features I am trying to implement is a comment/reply section on each post. In my post view I have a foreach loop that prints all the comments for that post.

```
@foreach (var comments in Model.Post.Comments)
{
if (comments.ReplyToId == 0)
{
    <p>@comments.Body <span><a href="#" class="toggleReply">Reply</a></span></p>

    <div id="replyTextBox" style="display:none">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Reply", "Comment", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <input type="hidden" name="PostId" value="@Model.Post.PostId" />
            <input type="hidden" name="CommentId" value="@comments.CommentId" />
            <input type="text" name="Body" id="CommentBody" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        }
    </div>
}

foreach (var reply in Model.Post.Comments)
{
    if(reply.ReplyToId == comments.CommentId)
    {
        <ul>
            <li>@reply.Body</li>
        </ul>    
    }
}
}
```

I have an if statement that checks the database to see if a comment is new comment, or a reply to a comment. Each new comment contains a reply button to allow a user to reply to a comment. I added some jquery to this button to hide or show the reply textbox.

Here is the jquery code:

```
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.toggleReply').click(function () {
            $('#replyTextBox').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

The problem i'm having is that because of the dynamic nature of these reply textboxes, only the first button seems to reveal a textbox. When I click on the other preceding reply buttons, only the textbox for the first reply button is affected.

Apologies for the less than concise explanation.

Comment: `id="replyTextBox"` ...Duplicate id....!

Comment: `CommentBody` is also a duplicate id

Comment: @MohammadAdil, what makes you think that it is duplicate?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov it's inside of a foreach

Comment: My mistake, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.toggleReply', function () {
        $('#replyTextBox').toggle();
    });
</script>
```

This will subscribe to the click event of all DOM elements matching the selector (`#toggleReply`) even if they don't exist when the DOM is initially loaded but are added subsequently. For this reason you don't need to wrap this code in a `$(document).ready()` as shown in my code sample.

Also notice that you might end up with duplicate ids here which results on invalid DOM:

```
<input type="text" name="Body" id="CommentBody" />
```

Same with `#replyTextBox`.

You might need to fix this:

```
@foreach (var comments in Model.Post.Comments)
{
    if (comments.ReplyToId == 0)
    {
        <p>@comments.Body <span><a href="#" class="toggleReply">Reply</a></span></p>

        <div class="replyTextBox" style="display:none">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Reply", "Comment", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <input type="hidden" name="PostId" value="@Model.Post.PostId" />
                <input type="hidden" name="CommentId" value="@comments.CommentId" />
                <input type="text" name="Body" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            }
        </div>
    }

    foreach (var reply in Model.Post.Comments)
    {
        if (reply.ReplyToId == comments.CommentId)
        {
            <ul>
                <li>@reply.Body</li>
            </ul>    
        }
    }
}
```

and adapt your script accordingly of course:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.toggleReply', function () {
        $(this).next('.replyTextBox').toggle();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Darin, I made suggested changes, however, if a reply button is clicked, all of the textboxes are displayed. Is this because they share the same class, and if so, what would be the best way to create unique classes for randomly generated buttons?

Comment: See my updated answer. Fix your dupe ids. And use a class selector: `$(this).next('.replyTextBox').toggle();` to match the corresponding element to be toggled.

Comment: Sorry @Darin, I didn't see additional information. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can have multiple elements on the page with the id #replyTextBox. jQuery select by id only returns a single element, in this case the first one. You should probably make your replyTextBox a class instead and select the one closest to this clicked toggle reply button:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.toggleReply').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.replyTextBox').toggle();
    });
});
```